# Querying Two tables

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need to count the number of records that match on the GIDs

```
Dim iSubscriptionCount 

SQLCommand = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter FROM Directories.GID, ClientSubscriptons.DirectoryGID FROM Directories, ClientSubscriptons WHERE Directories.GID = ClientSubscriptons.DirectoryGID;"
            rsTemp.Open SQLCommand, objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
            iSubscriptionCount = rsTemp("Counter")
            rsTemp.Close
            if iSubscriptionCount <= 0 then
                            %><a href="AddDirectory.asp?PGID=<% = rsDirectory("GID") %>"><% = GetIcon("Add", "Add Sub Directory", 25, True) %></a><%
```

I need to count the number of records that match on the GIDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not very clear... If you just want to count the match between the Directories and Client Subscriptions you have to perform a JOIN like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter FROM 
Directories join ClientSubscriptons
on Directories.GID = ClientSubscriptons.DirectoryGID
```

The Franchise Part is completely obscure... do you want to match the franchiseGID on both table?Then your query should looks like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter FROM 
Directories join ClientSubscriptons
on Directories.GID = ClientSubscriptons.DirectoryGID
and Directories.FranchiseGID = ClientSubscriptons.FranchiseGID
```

For more precise answers you need to be more clear please

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 from clauses...
The sql should read...

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter, Directories.GID, ClientSubscriptions.DirectoryGID
    FROM  Directories, ClientSubscriptions
   WHERE Directories.GID = ClientSubscriptions.DirectoryGID
```

You may also want a

```
 GROUP BY Directories.GID, ClientSubscriptions.DirectoryGID;
```

at the end

Comment: ClientSubscriptons is misspelled.  That is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much ¿Visual Basic? But you have two 'FROM' in the same sentence. Wouldn't

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter 
FROM Directories, ClientSubscriptons 
WHERE Directories.GID = ClientSubscriptons.DirectoryGID
```

Solve the problem?